# How to translate whole words into morse-code with a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, translation, morse-code

I'm writing a program that translates normal text to Morse code and I've written the core program that translates single letters to Morse code I still can't figure out how to translate whole words and text.

more clarification:
 i can translate single letters but i cant translate whole words

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *



#key down function
def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get() #this wil collect the text from the text entry box
    outpout.delete(0.0, END)
    try:
        definition = my_dictionary[entered_text]
    except:
        definition= "sorry an error occured"
    outpout.insert(END, definition)    



#### main
window = Tk()
window.title("THIS IS A SIMPLE TITLE")
window.configure(background="yellow")




#create label
Label (window,text="Enter a text here.", bg="YELLOW", fg="BLACK", font="arial 30 bold italic" ) .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#create a text entry box
textentry= Entry(window, width=20, bg="WHITE")
textentry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#add a submit button
Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=6, command=click) .grid(row=3 ,column=0, sticky=W)

#create another label
Label (window,text="THE ENCRYPTED TEXT IS:", bg="YELLOW", fg="BLACK", font="arial 10 bold" ) .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

#create a text box
outpout = Text(window, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, bg="WHITE")
outpout.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W) 

#the dictionary
my_dictionary = {
    "A" : ".-",
    "B" : "-...",
    "C" : "-.-.",
    "D" : "-..",
    "E" : ".",
    "F" : "..-.",
    "G" : "--.",
    "H" : "....",
    "I" : "..",
    "J" : ".---",
    "K" : "-.-",
    "L" : ".-..",
    "M" : "--",
    "N" : "-.",
    "O" : "---",
    "P" : ".--.",
    "Q" : "--.-",
    "R" : ".-.",
    "S" : "...",
    "T" : "-",
    "U" : "..-",
    "V" : "...-",
    "W" : ".--",
    "X" : "-..-",
    "Y" : "-.--",
    "Z" : "--..",
    " " : "/"
    }
#run the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"I can't figure out how to ..." is not a problem specification.

Comment: Morse is rather an _encoding_ than an encryption scheme.

Comment: There may be some better ways but simply, do what you're doing for a single character for an entire string of characters by iterating over input string and appending to the output string's end? This is pretty similar to the sum of an array(or a list) of numbers.

Comment: The new edit doesn't really change anything. You need to provide why you can't do what you can't do, what you've tried as well.

Comment: i haven´t tried something because as i said i´m new to python i don´t know lot of things i´m just asking for some help if someone can help me to be able to translate whole words instead of letters

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are trying to use the entire text as the key to the dictionary. So, if the text "A" is entered into the text input then it works as "A" is a key in `my_dictionary`. If the text "AS" is entered into the text box, this will fail as there is no key "AS" in `my_dictionary`.

What you will want to do, therefore, is loop over each of the characters in the entered string and add the Morse value of that letter to your definition string. You will also want to make sure that the letter is uppercase (unless it is guaranteed that the input will be upper case). This is done using the string `.upper()` method in the following example. Something like the following should do what you want.

```
definition = str()  # Create a blank string to add the Morse code to

# Go through each letter and add the Morse definition of the letter to definition
for letter in entered_text:
    definition += my_dict[letter.upper()]  # The upper makes sure the letter is a capital so that there will be a match in my_dict
```